# AMP-Analytics and AdSense Triggers for GA4 Integration

Tags: amp-html, adsense, google-analytics-4, amp-analytics

As far as I understand, the way the GA4-AdSense integration works is in a way where AdSense push events such as ad_impression, ad_click to ga4 directly from the visitor's browser (together with query_id parameter which then ga4 uses to receive additional data from the adsense platform...)

It seem to work pretty well in non-amp pages *(might miss an event property of ad_visible:true/false but that's a different story...)*

Main question is: **Is there a similar official/non official integration for AMP pages?** Maybe someone was able to implement the same integration manually? (I mean including the essential **query_id** event parameter...)

If not, does anyone knows if it's in Google's roadmap?

I searched for a solution a lot... I couldn't find any conversation/information about this.